# Editing result of joined/concatenated table result in PSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a sql query i'm running that joins & concatenates multiple tables, resulting in new columns, etc. I want to easily edit these fresh column values by double-clicking into the empty portions, like usual, but i read when joining tables they become read-only. I also wanted to attempt a regular INSERT cmd but don't understand what the table name is, since its all resulted from a lengthy query. How can i edit this queried table?

Below, i have pasted the query. For example, this spits out a new column change_products, and i want to edit those values but as mentioned above, cannot after joining/concatenating. Thanks!

```sql
SELECT change_ticket,
      change_product,
      change_desc,
      change_state,
      security_bulletin,
      change_assigned_to,
      affected,
      remediated
FROM change_tickets t1
  LEFT JOIN change_product_link t2 ON t1.id = t2.chg_id
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, concat(product_name, ' ', product_version) AS change_product FROM products) chg_product ON t2.product_id = chg_product.id
  LEFT JOIN change_sb_link t4 ON t1.id = t4.chg_id
  LEFT JOIN security_bulletins t5 ON t5.id = t4.sb_id
  LEFT JOIN product_sb_link t6 ON t5.id = t6.sb_id
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, concat(product_name, ' ', product_version) AS affected FROM products) aff_soft ON t6.affected_software_id = aff_soft.id
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, concat(product_name, ' ', product_version) AS remediated FROM products) rem_soft ON t6.remediated_software_id = rem_soft.id
                 WHERE change_state NOT IN ('Cancelled', 'Closed - Successful', 'Post-Verify') OR change_state IS NULL

ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: You can't "double click" anything in the output of `psql`

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules.html, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-update.html

Comment: You cannot "understand what the table name is" because there i no table name. Select produces a result set; it does not produce a table. The result set is 'in memory' only and then only until your procedure ends or it's transmitted to your application. You can use the data in the result set to Insert/Update/Delete any existing table you have the grants necessary. But it is your process logic making those decisions.